# Compilar a unidad de red con Angular

Tags: angular

Como se puede hacer para compilar Angular directamente en una unidad mapeada o ubicación de red?
ng build --prod
Así funciona bien (angular.json)

```
"options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/admin",
```

Pero lo hago así y no funciona

```
"options": {
            "outputPath": "Z:\miwebprincipal\admin\web",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, pero haciendo un .bat al que llamo desde "postbuild-prod"

```
"build-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href=/pagina/login/",
"postbuild-prod": "copiar.bat"
```

y el .bat es

```
 @echo off
xcopy /F "F:/source/MiProyecto/Entradas/admin/dist/admin/*.*" "Z:/miproyecto/web/login"
echo El archivo ha sido copiado!!
pause
exit
```

Comment: Vale, deberías marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, saludos.

Comment: no podes hacerlo vos? a mi no me deja

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es, en tu package.json añadir los siguiente:

```json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "postbuild-prod": "copyfiles ./dist/**/* Z:/miwebprincipal/admin/web",
  },
```

El `postbuild-prod` se ejecuta de manera inmediata y automática después de hacer el `npm run build-prod`.

Comment: Me tira lo siguiente
"copyfiles" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

Answer (score 0):

Probe con la respuesta de Oscar pero no me estaba funcionandohasta que me di cuenta de que no tenia instalado copyfiles

```
npm i -g copyfiles
```

Despues de instalarlo hice el build sin problemas